# juju error: flag provided but not defined: --force-machine

Tags: juju, maas, ceph

I am running command,

```
>juju deploy --config ceph.yaml --force-machine 1 local:ceph-osd
```

Which giving me error

```
error: flag provided but not defined: --force-machine
```

Any idea? if its syntax error or something else? 
My juju verson is 1.13.1-raring-amd64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it. Actually `--force-machine` has been replaced with `--to` in this new version of JuJu